# Pester 5.0 including ps1 file

Tags: pester

In version 4 I was using pester and in the begging of the test script I have this:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\..\Utilities.ps1"
```

Reading the Pester docs it is now saying to use everything before "Describe" into "BeforeAll" so I have done this:

```
BeforeAll {
    . "$PSScriptRoot\..\Utilities.ps1"
}
```

My problem is that the functions declared in the Utilities.ps1 are not visible for the tests, so I assume I should call that in another way. How should be the correct way to import another ps1 from a pester ps1 test script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had happened because I have code added in the "Describe" block. Moving the code to the "It" block worked for me.